# Random Points in polygon not created

Tags: qgis, polygon, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon shapefile with a single object and I want to create random points in it. The tool 'random points in polygon' in QGIS does it job well for polygon 1, but doesn't create any points for polygon 2 with a 'complexer' shape (even though a point layer is created). Somebody knows what could be the problem?

Data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hc9pHMdckLk_a0YigP-UseVjcNPkMbk3?usp=sharing

[image: Polygon1]

[image: Polygon 2]

Comment: Your second polygon has a complex shape, not a complex symmetry. Both polygons are in the same layer? Can you share your data for testing?

Comment: Sure, but I'm relativly new to StackExchange. How can I share data?

Comment: You can't share here. Upload to a cloud or webspace and share the link here (best edit you initial question and post it there).

Comment: Have you set a "Global minimum distance between points"? Maybe it cant find a solution

Comment: Setting a global minimum distance doesn't change anything

Comment: I have no problem creating random points in polygons, using your data (problematic shapefile). So you should check your settings and post a screeshot of the dialog window of `random points in polygons` to see what goes on. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztOgd.png

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is causing this issue, but I did find a workaround.

If you use the algorithm with the ID 'qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons' instead of 'native:randompointsinsidepolygons' you shouldn't run into this issue. This method seems to have slightly less control, but for most purposes should work fine.

Comment: Isn't that the same?

Comment: For me, it showed a different UI for the algorithms, and one worked and one didn't. So I guess not.